# Yii2: Login form multiple index with select condition

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I want to upgrade my application, with same login form but different index view, different application with in one login

the conditions what i want is if program "perjalanan dinas -> link to web/index.php" and if "file progress -> link to web/progress/index.php

[image]

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your problem/error? for me your question isn't clear

Comment: how to code that?? i don't know where i put if condition in action login

Comment: How to code is not a question fo SO. Here nobody code for you. You have to try to code your solution and then, if you get some error ask here